# No home point in Moveit Cartesian Plan Plugin in

Tags: rviz, moveit

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I have installed the Moveit Cartesian Plan Plugin in my rviz ,  when the "Move to Home" button is clicked, the robot move to the default origin pose  i cannot define. So could you tell me how to configure the plugin or change the code of  plugin to specify the "Home" point?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/273554/no-home-point-in-moveit-cartesian-plan-plugin-in/) by [pdmike](https://answers.ros.org/users/32007/pdmike/) on ROS Answers with karma: 43 on 2017-10-19

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [v4hn](https://answers.ros.org/users/4809/v4hn/) on 2017-10-20**:
What is the "Cartesian Plan Plugin"? I'm not aware of such a plugin/display for rviz.
If you want to add your own named poses in the motion planning display, add them to your srdf.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-01-05**:
@v4hn: the plugin that @pdmike is referring to is [fermi](http://wiki.ros.org/moveit_cartesian_plan_plugin). It's not an actual *planning plugin*, but a plugin similar to the MoveIt RViz plugin that interfaces with `computeCartesianPath(..)`.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-01-05**:
@pdmike: just to clarify: the name of the plugin is rather unfortunate: it's not an actual planning plugin (such as the OMPL or CHOMP planning plugins for MoveIt), but a plugin for RViz that provides a specific UI to `computeCartesianPath(..)`.

**Comment by [pdmike](https://answers.ros.org/users/32007/pdmike/) on 2018-01-05**:
@gvdhoorn: yes, but i think this plugin helped me a lot. When I need the robot trajectory with constraints which the endeffector should keep parallel to the ground, this plugin can easily define the waypoints without using computecartesianpath().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have  find a way to define the specific 'HOME ' in the Cartesian Plan Plugin.

1. Using the rviz to plan your robot model to your desired position and get the End_Effect link's position and orientation and each joint position
2. Changing the home_pose in '/moveit_cartesian_plan_plugin/src/generate_cartesian_path.cpp

   void GenerateCartesianPath::moveToHome()
   {

   ```
      geometry_msgs::Pose home_pose;
      home_pose.position.x=-0.161528;

      home_pose.position.y=0.258965;
      home_pose.position.z=0.829914;    
      home_pose.orientation.x = -0.275129;
      home_pose.orientation.y = 0.66813;
      home_pose.orientation.z = -0.625876;
      home_pose.orientation.w = 0.293575;
   ```
3. Compiling
4. Start the plugin and move the each joint to your home point approximately and click the "Move to Home" button

I don't know if this is a best way to change the default home point in this plugin, but it works. So you can try or you have another convenient way to solve it.

---

Originally posted by [pdmike](https://answers.ros.org/users/32007/pdmike/) with karma: 43 on 2018-01-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0